# solidity delegatecall prevention doesn't works

Tags: ethereum, solidity, uniswap

I am a newbie studying Uniswap V3's github code. I came up with [noDelegateCall.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/NoDelegateCall.sol) and I found out the way to prevent a contract to be delegatecalled from another cotract. As I tried to implement this, I caught up with the problem.

```
pragma solidity >0.8.0;

contract Receiver {
    string greeting = "Hello";
    address private immutable original;
    event Greeting(string greeting, address original, address addressThis);

    constructor() {
        original = address(this);
    }

    function checkNotDelegateCall() private view {
        require(address(this) == original);
    }

    modifier noDelegateCall() {
        checkNotDelegateCall();
        _;
    }
    
    function greet() external noDelegateCall {
        emit Greeting(greeting, original, address(this));
    }
}

contract Sender {
    string greeting = "Hi";
    
    function delegatedGreeting(address _contract) external {
        (bool success,) = _contract.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("greet()")
        );
    }
}
```

If I call function `delegatedGreeting`, I expect the function to be reverted because variables original and address(this) differs. However, although it emits an empty event, it still doesn't reverts. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

When the low-level delegatecall reverts, it doesn't automatically revert the main transaction. Instead, it returns `false` as the first return value of the `delegatecall()` function.

So you need to check the return value (in your case `bool success`) and validate that.

```
function delegatedGreeting(address _contract) external {
    (bool success,) = _contract.delegatecall(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("greet()")
    );
    require(success == true, "delegatecall failed");
}
```